# IIS8 windows Server shared folder app error 500

Tags: iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

Hello I installed a simple app in IIS on windowsServer 2012 and everything work good.

But the moment I share the app folder whit one organisational AD user  the app stop working and return 500

I do this on windows server 2008 on iis7  without any problem for years...

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply make the share from advanceShare option :)

Directly from share its broke the app...